# How to disable root web.config inheritance on my seekdotnet.com hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, windows

How to disable asp.net root web.config inheritance on my [seekdotnet.com](https://www.seekdotnet.com) hosting? For example, my website is www.example.com which already has web.config on it running on ASP.NET 4.5 framework.

And I have a subfolder which I have set as a virtual directory application: www.example.com/apps/invocing  which runs on MVC website http://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples/aspnet-web-pages

But the issue is it still auto inherits from the root web.config

**Note**: I try to use the comment `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` in the root web.config, and seems like still inherited the parent `/root` section. Why is asp.net hard to digest for php programmer like me?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

just realize that we need to actually disable the section one by one lol

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782252/avoid-web-config-inheritance-in-child-web-application-using-inheritinchildapplic

hi Andrew                                                                                                                       As the commenters for the previous answer mentioned, you cannot simply add the line

Just below . Instead, you need to wrap the individual web.config sections for which you want to disable inheritance. For example:

```
    <compilation>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
```

While  may work for some configuration sections, there are some that instead require a  directive, and still others don't seem to support either. In these situations, it's probably appropriate to set inheritInChildApplications="false".